# Should I leave a bad feedback for my manager or not?

Tags: feedback

I used to work as a recruiter but decided to change things and landed a job as a Personal Independence auditor in one of the biggest financial corporations. 
It's an underdog position but the process was new to Poland and I was one of the four people being hired. I was new in this job, let's put aside the fact that I was supposed to be hired in a risk mgmt position but something went wrong on the way and 2 weeks down the road I was told that it's gonna be Personal Independence.

I did not hate the job right away, but after 2 months. I realized that I'm not progressing in any of possible ways and that this job feels like a waste of time. I decided to change it and sought guidance from HR people. I had great advantage of being hired for a wrong position and having an HR manager friend. Soon, I was able to take part in recruitment processes inside the organization and after a week from the interview I was offered a new position.

You might think - great! But my current manager has become a nightmare. I mean, when I told him that I did not feel good in the position and that I should not be here he seemed to care and promised to ask around for options (it was Feb), then I was on a sick leave for a month after surgery so it kinda was pushed aside but when I came back I took it up again. It was the first time in my life when I cried in from of my superior. He made me feel like I was the worst employee on earth. Specifically, he told me that I was not good at my job and I should not expect much from other teams because: 
1. I have no valuable skills, 
2. I do not socialize well with people, and 
3. all other managers value what he has to say and he will not give me a good feedback.

Somehow, I managed to land this other position. I informed him and he would not believe that HR actually gave me consent to move. He just nodded and left the room without a word. Then, he began acting as if I was his enemy numero uno. On many occasions he would give me bad feedback, based on nothing, saying that my colleagues are afraid of me, that I create bad atmosphere in the team, and he even brought up a subject that I did not want to chip in for colleague's birthday, which by the way was not true.

It's 2 weeks until I change my roles. I came to work in the morning and I was greeted with "you made so many mistakes we don't know what to do with you, if I could I'd fire you today, do not do any more audits". Then I go to my colleagues and ask them about those mistakes and they don't know what I am talking about.

So my question is - should I leave a feedback in our internal database for all the people to see? The reasons I don't know are: 
1. I'm leaving and I don't want this to be seen as getting back at him, 
2. I'm just moving to other team so he can see it, he can share it and he is a true prick so he can take advantage of that feedback against me.

I'm torn because I really do want to share what I know about his true face with somebody but I do not want all the bad repercussions it can bring.

Comment: It's risky to complain about your manager, even on the internet, using your real name (if this is your real name, but it looks like one). Some managers also browse here, and it won't make your life more enjoyable if yours is one of them and he finds this.

Comment: You are still going to be in the same company as him. Don't leave a bad review. Just go. If he then continues to cause problems for you, report it to your new manager.

Comment: This is my real name but I kinda don't care if he sees it here. It's outside work, it's no lies, it's almost unoffensive. I really don't understand why we should not give bad feedback to anyone at all. Because it seems this way. How can we improve our workplace if somebody who misbehaves is not told that he is this way, or no one in power is told that somebody else is abusing his power?

Comment: If you feel so strongly about the need to give "feedback" to your boss, and you don't care about the consequences, then perhaps you should give it directly face to face rather than doing it over the internet.

Answer (score 5):

It's always tempting to try to return some of the abuse you've received. But it is rarely of any use to you - which should be your primary motivation here.

From the description your manager has reacted very badly to your decisions, it could well be described as bullying - but how would your new manager react if they saw a public post outlining your reaction? In any circumstances a company wide 'open letter' sounds risky.

Your new manager might read your post & think 'does this person react this badly every time things go against them?'. Which would be very bad.

There is no clean way to make a complaint without there being repercussions. In your situation I would **move into your new role, make a success of it & if in 6 months you are still determined that something needs to be done then go through official channels rather than using an internal 'open' database**.

If you have evidence that the manager is mistreating other staff members then go to HR immediately - but otherwise take your time & make sure that the complaint is worth the damage it may do to you.

Comment: "evidence" is the key word here. If the issue is worth a raise to HR, so be it. Otherwise it'll just be treated as a personal grudge, which can be used against you.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no clean way to make a complaint without there being repercussions. > In your situation I would move into your new role, make a success of it & if > in 6 months you are still determined that something needs to be done then go > through official channels rather than using an internal 'open' database.

I completely agree with this suggestion. Even if your manager is a toxic person try to make a success in your new position and don't follow his game. Once your HR supervisor will see your progress and successful work, such comments as you make "lot's of mistakes" will be false. 
I would suggest checking the situation at the start of August. If he still harassing you or start harassing others tell about this toxic behaviour for the main HR supervisor.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

No, that sounds like a bad idea. Passive aggression is rarely a productive set of behaviours. If you want results, go on the offensive. If you want to just endure the final weeks, just go passive.

If you really want to "get even", and in a way, "need to" get even then go all out agressive (but be smart about it)

Just arrange a 1-1 meeting with your boss and tell him to his face he is a total twat, a prime example asshat of the most senior kind. Let him know you are on to his lack of managerial skills. Let him know there is no possible way you can be bullied by him again. Let him know that if he pulls shit like this again you do everything you can to destroy his credibility. Let him know that is how everyone talks behind his back. (And, go really close, like Seinfeld-close-talker x2 when you do this)

The important thing is always: **Do not create a paper trail** Do not communicate any hostility in mail, memos or even in public. 1-on-1 is fine, but never anywhere else. Act 100% professionally before and after.

**If this is what you need to get back on track, then do it. You have made an enemy, but he was probably one before you did that.** This way you get to start your new position with a freshly executed power move. Remember, if you stare down into this abyss, it is going to stare back into you. Don't make this your usual mode of playing the politics game or else you will be the bully to the new employee after you...

**However, the most professional thing to do is to forget it ever happened and just decide never to accept being bullied again.** Decide that, whatever comes your way, your future is in *your hands*, not someone elses. If you get bad feedback, decide to either try to improve or find somewhere else to work. *You are in charge*. If people are bullies, let them know that they are. That is more than usually enough to silence them.